# Reference for format of PS1 string replacement in RHEL8

Tags: rhel, prompt, man

In RHEL8 the text of the command prompt presented to the user can be controlled by setting PS1. There are some format specifiers that can be used, for example using '\u' in the string will be replaced with the username. I have found the reference for the format replacements online but do they exist in a man page or info page on a standard RHEL8 install?

Answer (score 3):

Under 'PROMPTING' in the bash man page.

Comment: That is working thank you !

Comment: Please accept it as the answer by clicking the checkmark if it worked for you.